# How to use CVS in expect through SSH?

Tags: remote-access, expect, cvs

I can't find a way to pass CVS the password to run it automatically on the test server. I am trying to make a `expect` script.

I have a ssh alias, for which I made an `ssh-copy-id`, so the pasword handeling of `ssh` is no problems.

I would like to emulate :

```
ssh name;
run_remote_script.sh 
#(which triggers cvs update at the good place. Nb, the server has a MOTD)
expect "Password:"
send "${CVS_REMOTE_PASSWORD}\n" #enter the password
```

I made that :

```
#!/bin/bash

SOFT=$(basename $0)

if [ -z ${CVS_REMOTE_PASSWORD+x}  ];then
    echo "$SOFT : Undefined variable \$CVS_REMOTE_PASSWORD"
fi

hostname="company"

/usr/bin/expect <<EOD
spawn ssh $hostname
cvs_company.sh
expect "Password:"
send "$CVS_REMOTE_PASSWORD\n"
interact
EOD
```

I would like to point out that typing `ssh company`, though 'company' is a placeholder, in my console works perfectly fine.

What is wrong with my script ? It yields "Invalid command name cvs_company.sh while executing cvs_company.sh"

Is there a proper way of doing that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need something like this:

```
expect << EOD
spawn ssh $hostname
expect "YOUR-SHELL-PROMPT"
send "cvs_company.sh\r"
expect "Password:"
send "$CVS_REMOTE_PASSWORD\r"
interact
EOD
```

Comment: what does "interact" do in fact ? it caused me some problems.

Comment: Another lifesaver was setting the PS1 to something static.

Comment: `interact` is a command to return control back to the user. It essentially indicates that the automation part is finished. I would suggest in this case you don't want it, you want to expect the prompt, send `exit\r` and then `expect eof`

Comment: @PierreAntoineGuillaume - I copied your code. I'd think you want to interact with it after entering the password. :)

Comment: In the end I just removed the interact haha.

Comment: Then you should `expect eof` just as @glennjackman mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about how CVS authentication works, but see if you can do this:

```
ssh $hostname "echo '$CVS_REMOTE_PASSWORD' | cvs_company.sh"
```

This assumes your password does not contain single quotes. If it does, there are simple-but-ugly workarounds.

Expect is a fantastic tool, but in many cases you don't need to use it.